# Advertencia "Undefined variable: row in ..."

Tags: php, mysql, mysqli

He tratado de seguir un tutorial y adaptarlo a la necesidad de autocompletar un formulario mediante un input (con botón de Enviar).

Me sale el error:

> Notice:  Undefined variable: row in C:\xampp...\pacientebusqueda.php on line 61.

También me muestra el error de "Unknown column '...' in 'where clause". Les muestro el código (2 archivos):

**pacientebusqueda.php**

```
 <?php 
if (isset($_GET['action'])) { 
include_once('connections/connect.php');
$strsql = "SELECT codigo_pac, nombre, apellido_paterno FROM paciente WHERE codigo_pac=".$_GET['codigo_pac'];
$rs = mysqli_query($conn,$strsql) or die(mysqli_error($conn));
$row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($rs);
$total_rows = mysqli_num_rows($rs);    

} 
?>


<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
<meta charset="utf-8">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="http://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css">
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="pacientebusqueda.css">
<link href="css/jqueryui.css" type="text/css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<title>Advanced Search Form</title>




</head>

<body >
 <form>

<div class="form-group"  >
            <label>Ingrese el Código del Paciente</label>

            <input type="text" id="codigo_pac" value="<?php echo($row['codigo_pac']); ?>"" name ="codigo_pac" name ="codigo_pac">
            <input type="hidden" id="action" name="action" value="sent">
            <input type="submit" id="btn_submit" value="Enviar"> 
        </div>

        <div>
        <div class="form-group" >
            <label>Nombres</label>
            <input type="text" class="form-control" id="nombre" name ="nombre" value="<?php echo($row['nombre']); ?>">
        </div>
        <div class="form-group">
            <label>Apellido Paterno</label>
            <input type="text" class="form-control" id="apat" name ="apat" value="<?php echo($row['apellido_paterno']); ?>">
        </div>
</div>

<?php include_once('connections/connect.php');?>
<?php
$strsql = "SELECT codigo_pac,nombre,apellido_paterno FROM paciente ";
$rs = mysqli_query($conn,$strsql) or die(mysql_error($conn));
$row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($rs);
$total_rows = mysqli_num_rows($rs);
//print_r($row);
?>
<table width="800" border="0" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="2">
<tr>
    <td>Codigo</td>
    <td>Nombre</td>
    <td>Apellido Paterno</td>
  </tr>

 <?php if ($total_rows > 0) {
    do {
 ?>
 <tr>
    <td><?php echo($row['codigo_pac']); ?></td>
    <td><?php echo($row['nombre']); ?></td>
    <td><?php echo($row['apellido_paterno']); ?></td>
 </tr>
 <?php
    } while ( $row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($rs) );
    mysqli_free_result($rs);
 } else {
 ?>
<tr>
    <td colspan="3">No data found.</td>
</tr>

 <?php } ?>
 </table>
```

**connect.php**

```
<?php
$hostname_strcn = "localhost";
$database_strcn = "...";
$username_strcn = "root";
$password_strcn = "*****";
$conn = mysqli_connect($hostname_strcn, $username_strcn, $password_strcn) or 
die(mysqli_error($conn));
mysqli_select_db($conn, $database_strcn) or die(mysqli_error($conn));
?>
```

Mi base de datos consta de una tabla "paciente" (id, codigo_pac, nombre, apellido_paterno).

Comment: Hola, ¿podrías mostrar la estructura de la tabla pacientes de tu base de datos?

Comment: Yo que tú dejaba de usar ese tutorial INMEDIATAMENTE si te propone hacer consultas concatenando cadenas como `WHERE codigo_pac=".$_GET['codigo_pac']` o `value="<?php echo($row['nombre']); ?>"`. Debes evitar ese tipo de prácticas desde el principio y usar consultas preparadas para evitar [inyección SQL](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=EpKIhF7naSY) y `htmlspecialchars` para evitar inyección HTML/JS.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Vayamos por partes.

El mensaje "Notice: Undefined variable: row in C:\xampp...\pacientebusqueda.php on line 61." te aparece porque estás haciendo uso de una variable llamada `$row` cuando ésta no está definida.

¿Cuándo ocurre eso? Si vemos tu código tienes:

```
<?php
if (isset($_GET['action'])) {
    include_once('connections/connect.php');
    $strsql = "
      SELECT
        codigo_pac,
        nombre,
        apellido_paterno
      FROM paciente
      WHERE
        codigo_pac = '" . mysqli_real_escape_string($conn, $_GET['codigo_pac']) . "'
    ";
    $rs = mysqli_query($conn,$strsql) or die(mysqli_error($conn));
    $row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($rs);
    $total_rows = mysqli_num_rows($rs);
}
```

Defines el valor de `$row` sólo si has enviado el parámetro `action` por `GET`, pero cuando cargas la página sin enviarlo haces uso de dicha variable aquí:

```
<input type="text" id="codigo_pac" value="<?php echo($row['codigo_pac']); ?>"" name ="codigo_pac" name ="codigo_pac">
```

Independientemente de que la etiqueta HTML esté mal formada por no cerrar correctamente las comillas o por no usar `htmlspecialchars`, `$row` puede no existir y no lo has tenido en cuenta.

Ahora vayamos a por el mensaje de la columna no existente (debido a no haber formado correctamente la etiqueta).

Sólo tienes un `WHERE` en tu código, por lo que ésta es la única explicación plausible del problema:

Cuando envías el formulario los campos del formulario no están bien montados por contener una doble comilla y por haber un espacio innecesario entre el nombre del atributo y su contenido:

```
<input type="text" id="codigo_pac" value="<?php echo($row['codigo_pac']); ?>"" name ="codigo_pac" name ="codigo_pac">
```

Debería ser:

```
<input type="text" id="codigo_pac"
  value="<?= htmlspecialchars(isset($row['codigo_pac'])?$row['codigo_pac']:'') ?>"
  name="codigo_pac" />
```

Fíjate que he cambiado `name ="codigo_pac"` por `name="codigo_pac"`, he quitado el duplicado, y he hecho uso de [`htmlspecialchars()`](http://php.net/htmlspecialchars) para mostrar correctamente su contenido en un documento HTML.

Además, `isset($row['codigo_pac'])?$row['codigo_pac']:''` te permite generar una cadena vacía en caso de no haber sido enviado por `GET` el parámetro `codigo_pac` (y así evitar el mensaje de advertencia anterior).

El mensaje se debe a que estás concatenando en el SQL la cadena:

```
"WHERE codigo_pac=".$_GET['codigo_pac']
```

Y como no has montado bien el HTML no se envía dicho campo por `GET`, debiéndote haber soltado también un mensaje de advertencia diciendo que no existe ese índice y quedando la consulta:

```
WHERE codigo_pac=
```

Generalmente debería darte el siguiente mensaje de error:

> You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near '' at line 1

Comment: Muchas Gracias por la orientación OscarGarcia. (sigo teniendo dificultad que al ingresar el codigo de pac en el input) me muestra el error... Unknown column 'RBK' in 'where clause' .... ) el codigo de pac en la base de datos esta con 78-8111-RBK. (?)

Comment: Es debido a que no estás escapando la cadena a comprobar. Para ello deberías usar consultas preparadas, pero hasta dentro de un par de horas no puedo modificar la respuesta para decirte cómo hacerlo (aunque quizá deberías haber preguntado ambos errores por separado). Cuando edite dejaré comentario.

Comment: Por cierto, ese `78-8111-RBK` se interpreta como 78 menos 8111 menos el valor del campo `RBK`. De ahí el mensaje que te sale.

Comment: He publicado una edición rápida, luego la completo con más explicaciones.

Comment: Muchas gracias en verdad, la "edición rápida" que hiciste resolvió el problema al momento.. trabajaré en mejores consultas para evitar inyeccion sql... gracias OscarGarcia

Answer (score 0):

Creo que tu problema está en esta línea

```
<input type="text" id="codigo_pac" value="<?php echo($row['codigo_pac']); ?>"" name ="codigo_pac" name ="codigo_pac">
```

Fíjate que después de cerrar el php tienes dos dobles comillas. Eso hace que "name = ......" ya no se interprete como atributos html, sino como un texto literal en php.